# bbPress or WordPress + forum plugin?

Tags: bbpress, forum

I've been using bbPress for a while and I've noticed some bugs in my fresh installs. This makes me wonder if I should consider to just use WordPress with a forum plugin.

Any experience building a bbPress website?

Do you recommend a WordPress plugin to build forums?

Comment: bbPress is being (slowly) refactored into WP plugin. So better way to ask this question is if there are any good alternatives to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://simple-press.com/ on a few WordPress sites I have done and its been really good and I haven't had any problems with it. Alot of options, quite robust yet easy to use, it would be the one I would suggest trying.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with Tafts, Simple Press is very intuitive and easy to use. One word of warning though, if you are planning a big or very busy forum then this might not be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla isn't a wordpress plugin, but it's a forum and it can integrate with wordpress. Get it here: [vanillaforums.org](http://www.vanillaforums.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Simple Press is probably the most popular.  It's robust, but you can tell it is forced in there and doesn't always mesh with some themes.  If you use this, make sure you can make some template changes if necessary to get it to look right.

Vanilla forums is probably the easiest, (it's literally one line of code to implement).  It, again, looks little forced in there.  But otherwise, it's pretty easy to integrate.

BBpress has built in integration with WordPress, so it would probably be a little more seamless.  It also isn't the most widely supported yet, so it might not have all the features and extensions you want for it quite yet.

At the end of the day, define your goals for your Forum and move from there.